# Need help on clicking an element (Element is not clickable at point (62, 459)) - Capybara Ruby Selenium Automation

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, site-prism

I am having below error message in my console while trying to click on a button element:

```
unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (62, 459). 
Other element would receive the click: <i class="foo foo-chase-lemon font-size-13"></i>
```

Here's my code below:

```
@object = Page.new
@object.wait_until_btn_element_visible
@object.btn_element.click
```

I have tried with retry 5 times to click on it using rescue but didn't help.

Below code also didn't work where i tried to move to that element before click.

```
Capybara.page.driver.move_to.(@object.btn_element).perform
```

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is explaining the issue -- the <i> element is overlapping whatever you're trying to click on - depending on why it's overlapping you can try increasing the window size or scrolling the window so the element is no longer overlapped

Answer (score 0):

I tried increasing the resolution/ scrolling the window. None of them worked on this specific scenario. These solution might work for others.

However, I resolved the issue by clicking the button using javascript "execute_script" method in my automation script.